# Show that the set of solutions of a second order linear ODE with constants coefficients is a vector space of dimension 2

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, vector-spaces

Show that the set of solutions of the ODE:

$y''+a_0y'+a_1=0$

is a vector space of dimension 2.

I think this is false since $y(x)\equiv0$ is not in the set, is it possible the equation should be:

$y''+a_0y'+a_1y=0$  ?

Comment: Was is it a true or false question? Or investigate for which $a_1$ is it true? Of course as you said it could have been a typo.

Comment: it was a "Show this is true" kind of question, so is it a typo?

Comment: It should be a typo.